# Getting error for END IF in oracle while creating stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

While creating procedure, I am getting this error:

> Error(6384,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END"

```
PROCEDURE INS_WORKFLOW_FTTX_PARTIAL
(
  PJOB_PROGRESS_ID IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.JOB_PROGRESS_ID%TYPE,
  PSTATUS_ID IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.STATUS_ID%TYPE,
  PFSA_UG_ACTUAL IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.FSA_UG_ACTUAL%TYPE,
  PFSA_AR_ACTUAL IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.FSA_AERIAL_ACTUAL%TYPE,
  PMDU_ACTUAL_LENGTH IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.FSA_MDU_ACTUAL%TYPE,
  PAPPROVED_BY IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.APPROVED_BY%TYPE,
  PREJECTED_BY IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.REJECTED_BY%TYPE,
  PAPPROV_REJECT_REMARK IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.APPROV_REJECT_REMARK%TYPE,
  PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID%TYPE,
  PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME%TYPE,
  PUMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID%TYPE,
  PUMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME%TYPE,
  PHOTO_ACCEPTANCE_DATE IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.HOTO_ACCEPTENCE_DATE%TYPE,  
  PSPVENDORXML IN XMLTYPE,
  POUTMSG OUT NVARCHAR2
)

AS
VCNTSPVENCNT NUMBER :=0;
VJOB_ID NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN

SELECT JOB_ID INTO VJOB_ID FROM TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS WHERE JOB_PROGRESS_ID = PJOB_PROGRESS_ID;

SELECT COUNT(JOB_PROGRESS_ID) 
INTO VCOUNTERCHILD FROM TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS c INNER JOIN  TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS p 
            ON c.job_id=p.job_id and c.job_id = VJOB_ID and to_char(p.CREATED_DATE,'dd/mm/yyyy') = to_char(sysdate + 1,'dd/mm/yyyy') ;
            

IF VCOUNTERCHILD = 0
            THEN BEGIN
                INSERT INTO TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS
              (
                JOB_ID,
                STATUS_ID,
                HOTO_OFFERED_DATE,
                APPROV_REJECT_REMARK,
                HOTO_OFFERED_LENGTH,
                NE_SPAN_LENGTH,
                CREATED_BY,
                UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID,
                UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME,
                UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID,
                UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME,
                UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_DATE,
                MODIFIED_BY,
                MODIFIED_DATE,
                APPROVED_BY,
                APPROVED_DATE,
                FSA_UG_ACTUAL,
                FSA_AERIAL_ACTUAL,
                FSA_MDU_ACTUAL
              )
              VALUES
              (
                VJOB_ID,
                PSTATUS_ID,
                TO_DATE(PHOTO_OFFERED_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY'),
                PAPPROV_REJECT_REMARK,
                PHOTO_OFFERED_LENGTH,                
                PNELENGTH,
                PCREATED_BY,
                PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID,
                PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME,
                PUMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID,
                PUMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME,
                SYSDATE,
                PAPPROVED_BY,
                SYSDATE,
                PCREATED_BY,
                SYSDATE,
                PFSA_UG_ACTUAL,
                PFSA_AERIAL_ACTUAL,
                PFSA_MDU_ACTUAL
              )RETURNING JOB_PROGRESS_ID INTO PJOB_PROGRESS_ID;
            END;
            
  IF PJOB_PROGRESS_ID > 0 
          THEN
              POUTMSG := 'SUCCESS|'||PJOB_PROGRESS_ID;
              UPDATE TBL_FIBER_INV_MSTDATA SET REQUEST_ID = VJOB_ID WHERE SPAN_LINK_ID = SPLKID AND MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = PMAINTENANCEZONECODE;  
              COMMIT;
          ELSE
             POUTMSG := 'WARNING|Record not created - Already a child record for job id '||PJOB_PROGRESS_ID_OLD||' ';
            
          END IF; 
END;
END;
            

END INS_WORKFLOW_FTTX_PARTIAL;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is about poor formatting. If you indented code as you should, you'd easier spot what's wrong (missing END IF, superfluous END):

```
PROCEDURE ins_workflow_fttx_partial (
    pjob_progress_id       IN tbl_fiber_inv_job_progress.job_progress_id%TYPE,
    pstatus_id             IN tbl_fiber_inv_job_progress.status_id%TYPE,
    pfsa_ug_actual         IN tbl_fiber_inv_job_progress.fsa_ug_actual%TYPE,
    pfsa_ar_actual         IN tbl_fiber_inv_job_progress.fsa_aerial_actual%TYPE,
    pmdu_actual_length     IN tbl_fiber_inv_job_progress.fsa_mdu_actual%TYPE,
    papproved_by           IN tbl_fiber_inv_job_progress.approved_by%TYPE,
    prejected_by           IN tbl_fiber_inv_job_progress.rejected_by%TYPE,
    papprov_reject_remark  IN tbl_fiber_inv_job_progress.approv_reject_remark%TYPE,
    pums_group_ass_by_id   IN tbl_fiber_inv_job_progress.ums_group_ass_by_id%TYPE,
    pums_group_ass_by_name IN tbl_fiber_inv_job_progress.ums_group_ass_by_name%TYPE,
    pums_group_ass_to_id   IN tbl_fiber_inv_job_progress.ums_group_ass_to_id%TYPE,
    pums_group_ass_to_name IN tbl_fiber_inv_job_progress.ums_group_ass_to_name%TYPE,
    photo_acceptance_date  IN tbl_fiber_inv_job_progress.hoto_acceptence_date%TYPE,
    pspvendorxml           IN XMLTYPE,
    poutmsg                OUT NVARCHAR2
) AS
    vcntspvencnt NUMBER := 0;
    vjob_id      NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    SELECT
        job_id
    INTO vjob_id
    FROM
        tbl_fiber_inv_job_progress
    WHERE
        job_progress_id = pjob_progress_id;

    SELECT
        COUNT(job_progress_id)
    INTO vcounterchild
    FROM
             tbl_fiber_inv_job_progress c
        INNER JOIN tbl_fiber_inv_jobs p ON c.job_id = p.job_id
                                           AND c.job_id = vjob_id
                                           AND to_char(p.created_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') = to_char(sysdate + 1, 'dd/mm/yyyy');

    IF vcounterchild = 0 THEN
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO tbl_fiber_inv_job_progress (
                job_id,
                status_id,
                hoto_offered_date,
                approv_reject_remark,
                hoto_offered_length,
                ne_span_length,
                created_by,
                ums_group_ass_by_id,
                ums_group_ass_by_name,
                ums_group_ass_to_id,
                ums_group_ass_to_name,
                ums_group_ass_to_date,
                modified_by,
                modified_date,
                approved_by,
                approved_date,
                fsa_ug_actual,
                fsa_aerial_actual,
                fsa_mdu_actual
            ) VALUES (
                vjob_id,
                pstatus_id,
                to_date(photo_offered_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
                papprov_reject_remark,
                photo_offered_length,
                pnelength,
                pcreated_by,
                pums_group_ass_by_id,
                pums_group_ass_by_name,
                pums_group_ass_to_id,
                pums_group_ass_to_name,
                sysdate,
                papproved_by,
                sysdate,
                pcreated_by,
                sysdate,
                pfsa_ug_actual,
                pfsa_aerial_actual,
                pfsa_mdu_actual
            ) RETURNING job_progress_id INTO pjob_progress_id;

        END;

        IF pjob_progress_id > 0 THEN
            poutmsg := 'SUCCESS|' || pjob_progress_id;
            UPDATE tbl_fiber_inv_mstdata
            SET
                request_id = vjob_id
            WHERE
                    span_link_id = splkid
                AND maintenance_zone_code = pmaintenancezonecode;

            COMMIT;
        ELSE
            poutmsg := 'WARNING|Record not created - Already a child record for job id '
                       || pjob_progress_id_old
                       || ' ';
        END IF;

    END IF;
END ins_workflow_fttx_partial;
```