# Oracle procedure is not working due to syntax rror

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Below is the Stoed procedure which is giving error as

> Error(51,5): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare else elsif end exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with          << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge json_exists json_value json_query    json_object json_array

```
create or replace PROCEDURE GET_SAPID_CREATION_INFO
AS 

ERROR_CODE NUMBER;
ERROR_MESSAGE NVARCHAR2(200);

VAR_SAPID_COUNT NUMBER;
VAR_ROW_ID NUMBER;
VAR_COUNT NUMBER;

BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(1)
INTO VAR_COUNT
FROM TBL_PRE_POST_HOTO
WHERE CREATION_SAPID IS NULL
AND SAPID_REMARKS NOT LIKE '%Sap Id :-%';

 -- create log table 'start' 'End'

INSERT INTO TBL_CMP_SAP_ID_ERRORLOG
(
  USERNAME, SAP_ID, ERROR_MESSAGE, ERROR_TYPE, LOG_DATE)
VALUES('SCHEDULER','', 'SCHDULER STARTED','', SYSDATE); 

COMMIT;
 
IF VAR_COUNT > 0 THEN

for cur_sapid in ( 
                  select SAP_ID,
                         UNIQUEID,
                         CRNO,
                         CMP_ID,
                         PROCESS_REMARK
                  FROM APP_WFM.SAPID_INPUTDATA_ENODEB       
               )
  loop         
  
  update TBL_PRE_POST_HOTO
  set CREATION_SAPID = cur_sapid.SAP_ID,
      SAPID_REMARKS =  cur_sapid.PROCESS_REMARK
where ID = cur_sapid.CMP_ID;


COMMIT;  
 
end loop;   

    
    EXCEPTION  
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      ERROR_CODE := SQLCODE;
      ERROR_MESSAGE := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200);

      ROLLBACK;

END;
INSERT INTO TBL_CMP_SAP_ID_ERRORLOG
(
  USERNAME, SAP_ID, ERROR_MESSAGE, ERROR_TYPE, LOG_DATE)
VALUES('SCHEDULER',cur_sapid.SAP_ID, ERROR_CODE||' : '||ERROR_MESSAGE, ERROR_CODE, SYSDATE);  
COMMIT;


END;
END GET_SAPID_CREATION_INFO;
```

Comment: Each END is supposed to end a block of code that starts with a begin. 'END LOOP' ends a LOOP. Count how many ends you have and how many begins.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77721212/ The OP had exactly the same issues in their previous question (flow control statements without matching closing tags exacerbated by poorly formatted code). Exactly the same advice and solution applies in this question. Why this was re-opened after it was closed, I do not know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear which exception you're handling (its scope);

- is it `update` within the loop (I guess so) - in that case, it requires *internal* `begin-exception-end` block so that if anything goes wrong, you *record it* (by insert into the log table) and let other loop rounds to be executed, or
- is it the whole procedure (I don't think so, because the last `insert` references cursor variable which isn't accessible otuside of the loop)?

Anyway: as you've been told, you should carefully count & match all "begins" with their "ends".

---

Apart from that, you shouldn't `commit` within a procedure, especially not within a loop. You'll get inconsistent data if anything goes wrong as modifications will partially be updated (and commited). Let the caller commit.

So (with included logging info, as requested in a comment):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_sapid_creation_info
AS
   var_count      NUMBER;
   ERROR_CODE     NUMBER;
   error_message  NVARCHAR2 (200);
   l_cnt          NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (1)
     INTO var_count
     FROM tbl_pre_post_hoto
    WHERE     creation_sapid IS NULL
          AND sapid_remarks NOT LIKE '%Sap Id :-%';

   -- create log table 'start' 'End'

   INSERT INTO tbl_cmp_sap_id_errorlog (username, error_message, log_date)
        VALUES ('SCHEDULER', 'SCHDULER STARTED', SYSDATE);

   IF var_count > 0
   THEN
      FOR cur_sapid
         IN (SELECT sap_id,
                    uniqueid,
                    crno,
                    cmp_id,
                    process_remark
               FROM app_wfm.sapid_inputdata_enodeb)
      LOOP
         BEGIN
            UPDATE tbl_pre_post_hoto
               SET creation_sapid = cur_sapid.sap_id,
                   sapid_remarks = cur_sapid.process_remark
             WHERE id = cur_sapid.cmp_id;
             
             l_cnt := l_cnt + sql%rowcount;
         EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS
            THEN
               ERROR_CODE := SQLCODE;
               error_message := SUBSTR (SQLERRM, 1, 200);

               INSERT INTO tbl_cmp_sap_id_errorlog (username,
                                                    sap_id,
                                                    error_message,
                                                    ERROR_TYPE,
                                                    log_date)
                    VALUES ('SCHEDULER',
                            cur_sapid.sap_id,
                            ERROR_CODE || ' : ' || error_message,
                            ERROR_CODE,
                            SYSDATE);
         END;
      END LOOP;

      INSERT INTO tbl_cmp_sap_id_errorlog (username,
                                           error_message,
                                           log_date)
           VALUES ('SCHEDULER',
                   'Total number of updated rows = ' || l_cnt,
                   SYSDATE);
   END IF;
END get_sapid_creation_info;
```

Then you'd call it as

```
begin
  get_sapid_creation_info;
end;
```

Once it is done, check the result:

```
select * From tbl_cmp_sap_id_errorlog where ...
```

and - if you're satisfied with the outcome (no errors), **then** commit. Otherwise, rollback, fix what's wrong and re-run the procedure until there are no errors.

Comment: Yes it's working now. Can you help me as how do u format the query

Comment: How do you write queries? In text editor? If so, format it manually or use one of online formatters, e.g. https://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm . If you use GUI tool, it probably has formatting option. TOAD uses [CTRL + SHIFT + F] combination. SQL Developer uses [CTRL + F7].

Comment: Also, how Can i check with above query as how many records got actually updated and **on what date**?

Comment: No, unless you log that info. One option is to create additional local variable to count number of updated rows and increase its value after each update as `l_cnt := nvl(l_cnt, 0) + sql%rowcount;`. Then store its value, as well as SYSDATE into tbl_cmp_sap_id_errorlog  table with that additional information.

Comment: oh, can u update it in your above answer, if possible so that I can verify the same.?

Comment: Yes; have a look, please.

Comment: Thanks littlefoot, will update you when its totally in use

Answer (score 0):

1. Format your code neatly and indent it consistently according to the flow control statements - if you do that then **YOU** will be able to easily see these issues without having to ask on Stackoverflow.
2. Look at the flow control statements in your code and make sure that each starting flow control statement has the corresponding terminating statement. I.e. `BEGIN ... [EXCEPTION] ... END`, `IF ... END IF`, `FOR ... IN ... LOOP ... END LOOP`, etc.

Your code, with only the flow control statements, is:

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE GET_SAPID_CREATION_INFO
AS 
  ...

BEGIN
  IF ... THEN
    for ... in ( ... )
    loop
      ...
    end loop;   
EXCEPTION  
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ...
END;
END;
END GET_SAPID_CREATION_INFO;
```

You have:

- `IF` without a corresponding `END IF`.
- Too many `END` statements.

To fix it, add an `END IF` statement and remove the penultimate two `END` statements that do not have matching `BEGIN` statements.

As an aside, do not `COMMIT` in procedures (and especially not in loops within procedures) as it will prevent you from chaining multiple procedures together and then if there is an error with a later procedure then using `ROLLBACK` to roll them all back. In loops it is worse as you can perform half the modifications and then get an error and if you `COMMIT` in each loop then you will not be able to `ROLLBACK` and your data may be left in an inconsistent state (and, apart from the logical issues, it is also very inefficient to use many `COMMIT`s so it will make your code very slow and write lots to the log files). Instead, you should `COMMIT` once from the code that calls the procedure.